# Ubuntu phone (bq aquaris) camera stopped working after system update

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch, phone, camera

After the last system update,to 15.04 r25 version, the camera is not working. I only get a black screen when it is turned on.

Comment: Because of the **very specific** rules I can neither upvote or comment. So I would just like to register that I am suffering from the **exact** same problem, brought about by the exact same problems. I have done the exact same things, and **have** done both safe boots and the hardware test. This answer may be deleted by the StackExchange people, but I hope they file some sort of report saying that StackExchange users from other StackExchange subjects **should** be allowed to *at least* upvote a problem / question.

Answer (score 2):

Did you receive a prompt asking you to allow the Camera app to access the phone camera?

If not, you can check in *System Settings - Security and Privacy - Other application accesses - Camera*, and confirm if the check item for Camera is ticked.

Comment: Yes, the camera app is authorized to access the phone camera. Thanks, but it is not working.